# JavaScript not showing exact value in calculations

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, math

I would like to know why there is always some difference in value, when I perform the below calculations.

```js
var amt=1000;
var cr= 3.02;
var net = (cr/100)*amt;
console.log(net); //shows 29.02 instead of 30.02
```

Comment: I dont think that percentage sign is doing what you think it is.

Comment: @zero298 thanks for reply, sorry there is no %

Comment: showing me `30.200000000000003`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: There won't be any difference. It will always output `30.200000000000003`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `*` before `/`.

```js
var amt = 1000;
var cr = 3.02;
var net = cr * amt / 100;
console.log(net);
```